# Is there a simple way to write a method that returns the logical AND of the boolean elements contained in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, boolean

I have a linked list of n boolean elements and i should write a method that returns the logical AND of those elements.

```
public class Element{

boolean bool;
Element next;

public Element(boolean bool, Element next){
    this.bool=bool;
    this.next=next;
}
```

}

```
public class List{

Random rand= new Random();
Element e=null;

public List(int n){       
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ 
        e= new Element(rand.nextBoolean(),e);

    }    
}
```

I thought about creating an array, loop through the list, fill the array with the logical AND values, then return the array.
Honestly i don't think it would be a good solution for various reasons.
Can i do that without arrays?

Comment: If the list has a single false, the AND of the list will be false, otherwise true.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Java's `LinkedList` and `contains` :

```
LinkedList<Boolean> myList = new LinkedList<>();

// add a bunch of true's
myList.add(true);
myList.add(true);
myList.add(true);
myList.add(true);

System.out.println("logicalAND="+!myList.contains(false));

// add a false
myList.add(false);
System.out.println("logicalAND="+!myList.contains(false));
```

prints

```
logicalAND=true
logicalAND=false
```

If your list element is more complex but still needs to resolve equality on the Boolean value then be sure to update its `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding the question here, but if you're trying to get the boolean and of a whole chunk, isn't that just true if everything is true, false otherwise?

Here's some vague code of my thinking

```
boolean value=true;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ //traverse the nodes
    if( /*Value at the node you're at*/==false )
        value=false;
}
return value;
```

Comment: Don't compare an boolean with a boolean in a condition. This is bad practice. Therefore, you should simply use ```if (!/*Value at the node you're at*/)```

Comment: This isn't intended to be proper code, I was just doing that to make the code as visually clear as possible, but yeah, D. Lawrence is correct!

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion and write a Method in your Element class like this:

```
boolean andAll() {
    return (next!=null) ? bool && next.andAll() : bool;
}
```

If bool is false, Java won't evaluate the part on the left side of that expression.
You can write an interface method in your list class to call that method on your first list Element.

If your target isn't creating a new implementation of linked list, you should use the LinkedList delivered by Java and it's contains method.

Greetings